# Extra brackets appearing in styled theorem in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xparse}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@namespace\@namespacefalse
\newcommand{\contrel}[2]{
\if@namespace
    Continua da
\else
    #1~--~continua da
\fi
\ #2
}
\thmt@define@thmuse@key{continued}{%
  \thmt@suspendcounter{\thmt@envname}{\thmt@trivialref{#1}{??}}%
  \g@addto@macro\thmt@newoptarg{{}%
    \thm@continues{#1}%
    \@iden}%
}
\newcommand\thm@continues[1]{%
  \ifcsname hyperref\endcsname
    \hyperref[#1]
  \else
    {}
  \fi
  {\contrel{\nameref*{#1}}{\cont@from}}%
}
\makeatother
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
postheadspace=.5em,
name={\ignorespaces},
numbered=no,
headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}moo}
    {\IfValueTF{#4}
        {\gdef\cont@from{#4}
        \begin{@thmattr}[name={\protect\nameref*{#3}},continued=#3]}
        {\IfValueTF{#3}
            {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2,label=#3]}
            {\begin{@thmattr}[name=#1\ #2]}
        }
    }
    {\end{@thmattr}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{teorspec}[Principio]{di D'Alembert}
Foobar.
\end{teorspec}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Everything is fine, except those brackets are evidently out of place. Indeed, I said `notebraces={}{}`, which should have suppressed them, and does suppress them in `report`, a thing I've been exploiting for the past over a year. So why is `beamer` putting those brackets back? And how do I get rid of them?

**Update**

I added the `\makeatletter` part. THat `\if@namespace` is for a purpose I don't quite remember, but it seems useless in this particular theorem. Left it to have the code the way it is in the package. I will look into how to get rid of it, perhaps.

**Update 2**

I accepted egreg's answer since the code he gave solved my problem. However, I would still like to know why the problem was there in the first place. What is beamer doing that conflicts with my code? And more importantly, should I ask a new question about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `name` does in the options to a theorem. Since I don't understand what `continued` is for and what `\nameref*{#3}` is supposed to do, I'll show just the basics:

```
\documentclass[notheorems,slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xparse}

\protected\def\thistheoremname{}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  postheadspace=.5em,
  name={\thistheoremname},
  numbered=no,
  headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}m}
 {\def\thistheoremname{#1 #2}\begin{@thmattr}}
 {\end{@thmattr}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{teorspec}[Principio]{di D'Alembert}
Foobar.
\end{teorspec}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right that I forgot the definition of `continued`: copying stuff off a package it is easy to forget bits. It is my personal version of `continues` or whatever it is. Will add it in soon. The `\nameref` recovers the name of the theorem in the case it is continued. What would I be misunderstanding about `name`? In `report` this behaves as expected..

Comment: AFAIK in `report`, if I use `\newtheorem` and then provide a `name`, I get a bold "Thm kind \the thm counter` (name).", then the theorem is typeset in Italics. Does this change in Beamer? With that theorem style, no counter nor kind, and the brackets should be suppressed. No?

Comment: It does seem strange that after suppressing the name I have a name fed in to the `@thmattr`, now that I see it... but it always worked...

Comment: @MickG `beamer` does many redefinitions and it's surely possible that `tmhtools` conflicts with it.

Comment: question updated. I will probably implement your solution because it works in Beamer as well as other classes. I would really like to know what happens with Beamer and `thmtools` though…

Comment: Why `\protected`? Why not just `\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}`?

Comment: @MickG Because `thmtools` dors `\edef`

Comment: Mm, what does `\protected` do?

Comment: A macro defined as `\protected` is not expanded when `\edef` is doing its full expansion of the replacement text.

Comment: What if I want to label such theorems? I tried [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8kmew.png) and it seems the name just won't make it to the `aux`, even if I `\protect` it in the definition of the style…

Comment: @MickG Do you really need `\nameref` in a presentation? However this is a new question.

Comment: Actually I tried putting your definition (well, my version of it, the one in the pic) in a package I use in every document, and I found this problem. For now I have a choice option to choose which to use, but I had rather remove that extra option.

Comment: I'll ask a new question. Tomorrow though. Now it's bedtime. Goodnight :).

Comment: Have been busy with my thesis. Today I take a breath and… [ask this follow-up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277121/theorem-name-not-making-it-to-the-aux) :).