# Theorem name not making it to the aux

Tags: beamer, theorems, labels, auxiliary-files, thmtools

I posted [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275257/extra-brackets-appearing-in-styled-theorem-in-beamer). egreg answered. I applied his solution to my presentation. It worked. Then I tried it in my thesis, where I use references, and I realized the theorem names weren't making it to the `aux` for some reason. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[notheorems,slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xparse,lipsum,hyperref}

\protected\def\thistheoremname{}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  postheadspace=.5em,
  name={\thistheoremname},
  numbered=no,
  headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}mo}
 {\def\thistheoremname{#1 #2}
 \IfValueTF{#3}
     {\begin{@thmattr}[label=#3]}
     {\begin{@thmattr}}}
 {\end{@thmattr}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{teorspec}[Principio]{di D'Alembert}[thm:spec:Dalemb]
Foobar.
\end{teorspec}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Abbiamo poco fa enunciato il \nameref{thm:spec:Dalemb}, o principio del vincolo liscio.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now I realize a presentation is not quite a place for references, but I was too lazy to change the class or create a MWE of my own, so I just added necessary edits to egreg's answer's code. As you see if you compile, the reference doesn't work:

[image]

The generated `aux` reads:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\beamer@endinputifotherversion {3.33pt}}
\@writefile{nav}{\beamer@endinputifotherversion {3.33pt}}
\newlabel{thm:spec:Dalemb}{{}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
\@writefile{snm}{\beamer@slide {thm:spec:Dalemb}{1}}
\@writefile{loe}{\contentsline {@thmattr}{\numberline {\let \autodot \@empty }Principio di D'Alembert}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\slideentry {0}{0}{1}{1/1}{}{0}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@framepages {1}{1}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\slideentry {0}{0}{2}{2/2}{}{0}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@framepages {2}{2}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\slideentry {0}{0}{3}{3/3}{}{0}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@framepages {3}{3}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@partpages {1}{3}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@subsectionpages {1}{3}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@sectionpages {1}{3}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\beamer@documentpages {3}}}
\@writefile{nav}{\headcommand {\def \inserttotalframenumber {3}}}
```

In particular, the label's line `\newlabel{thm:spec:Dalemb}{{}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}` has an empty `{}` instead of the correct `{Principio di D'Alembert}`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: \nameref is defined by hyperref and uses a whole lot of beamer and amsthm specific code.  Things like \NR@gettitle{#3}%  This is NOT going to be easy.

Comment: I forgot to load `hyperref`, @JohnKormylo, sorry. I always use it. I'll add it to the code, it shouldn't change the result... right?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. But `\nameref` is available without that package, so why do you state it is "defined by `hyperref`? Did you mean REdefined?

Comment: Beamer automatically loads hyperef.  I searched all the sty files (at telast all the ones I have installed) and found \nameref used only in hyperref,syt nameref.sty and memopir.cls.  BTW, you realize that \nameref is supposed to return the name of the counter, not the theorem?

Comment: @JohnKornylo WHAT?? How does the name make sense then?? And why did it work with the other definition? It's not like the counter was renamed every time...?

Comment: I looked at the `hyperref` definition, and for what I understand it should return the 3rd argument of the label, which is empty in this case, but in the case of `\newlabel{thm:spec:Poinc}{{}{9}{Lemma\ di Poincaré}{thmt@dummyctr.dummy.17}{}}` it's `Lemma\ di Poincaré`. Got this off my thesis, which uses the other definition of `teorspec`.

Comment: `{}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}`, look at how the dummy counter is `Doc-Start`… is that Beamer?

Comment: Same for `nameref`.

Comment: My mistake.  It may be called  \@currentlabelname but sometimes it contains other strings (like the section name after \section).  BTW, Doc-Start is the hypertarget name (default).

Comment: The counter name goes in arg 1, right @John?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `\label` is set by the last \refstepcounter, but since the hypertarget part isn't working, it doesn't really matter.

```
\documentclass[slidescentered]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xparse,lipsum,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\thistheoremname{}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  postheadspace=.5em,
  name={\thistheoremname},
  numbered=no,
  headpunct=.]
{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{@thmattr}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{teorspec}{O{Teorema}mo}
 {\def\thistheoremname{#1 #2}%
 \refstepcounter{theorem}%
 \edef\@currentlabelname{#2}%
 \label{#3}%
 \begin{@thmattr}}
 {\end{@thmattr}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{teorspec}[Principio]{di D'Alembert}[thm:spec:Dalemb]
Foobar.
\end{teorspec}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Abbiamo poco fa enunciato il \nameref{thm:spec:Dalemb}, o principio del vincolo liscio.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you meant `#1 #2` for `\@currentlabelname`.

Comment: I tried it and it seems the only relevant addition is `\edef\@currentlabelname{#2}`: commenting out the counter line (`\refstepcounter`) has no effect.

Comment: So why does the name not get to the aux without the `\edef` above? Otherwise known as: why does this fix work?

Comment: Names are inserted into \@currentlabelname on a case by case basis.  In general it is left emply.